# Smoke Simulation Problem. I can't describe it

Tags: smoke-simulation

...I'm at the end of my rope with smoke simulation in Blender. I've tried baking the smoke, but it doesn't work. The Blender version also doesn't matter, as this issue is a thing whether I'm in 2.8, or 2.93. This picture below explains my issue better than I ever could.

[image: Smoke problem]

...That ain't smoke. I am also using the default quick smoke settings, so that's not the cause of this. The only thing I can think of being the issue is....... my laptop. I really hope that's not the case, because I can't get a new pc for a while.

My laptop specs:

CPU: AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6, 10 Compute Cores. (4C + 6G... I'm assuming the C is CPU while the G is GPU)

Video Card: Radeon R6 Graphics. My drivers are all up to date according to device manager.

8GB Ram.

I'm using Windows 10, and my harddrive is 1T.

I also crossposted this to the Blender subreddit. I could really use some advice and/or laptop/pc reccomendations for when I can upgrade. Smoke simulation is really important for the animations I want to eventually do.

The issue also happens with any smoke sim I do, the mesh doesn't make any difference.

I would be eternally grateful for any and all help regarding this. Thank you so much for your time reading about my problem.

Comment: does it look this way when you render?

Comment: Yes.... RIP any chances of doing smoke simulation in Blender for the time being.

Comment: It sounds like a graphics card problem to me, although I'm by no means an expert.  =(  I hope its something you can fix without getting a new laptop.

Comment: I assume you're using eevee, what happens when you switch to cycles?

Comment: Same results in Cycles. That sucks.... I recently came across some good smoke tutorials, and I can't even follow along.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that really sucks.  When you do upgrade, I would suggest you get a desktop pc vs a laptop, it's more customizable, upgradeable, and it doesn't break as fast. My opinion anyway.  =)

Comment: I have the same problem. I *did*, however, get the smoke to work sometimes. I just can't remember *how* I did it (that sucks, doesn't it?). I'm pretty sure that it's not your laptop that's causing this problem. Will let you know if I find anything more.

Comment: I had this problem as well, Try using the Radeon ProRender for Blender instead of Cycles.
[https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-downloads](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-downloads#Blender) Hope this works

Comment: You could share the file, and then the people answering the question will be able to tell you if the answer is in the Blender settings.

Comment: An easy way to know if it's something specific with your system would be to share your file with us.

Comment: Just uploaded a simple cube that uses the quick smoke sim. Same issue in 3.0... tested with both Eevee and Cycles using CPU and GPU Compute. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=eLbpp89B" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/eLbpp89B/)